# Check out Project from Version Control Fails

Tags: android, git, android-studio, google-glass

I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 on Mac to develop an app for Google Glass. I have been trying to start with one of the recommended projects that Google supplies on github, but I'm running into a problem. The instructions say to open Android Studio, select *Check Out Project from Version Control*, select Git in the dropdown menu, choose a location for the files, and then paste the url to the github. So I paste the url and when I click the *test* button to check the vcs repository url, it says the connection is successful. The problem occurs after I click *Clone* in this window. All documentation that I have read states that one or two more windows should pop up and that I should select *OK* in both of them, however, nothing ever shows up. The project never opens, and when I try to find the project following the path I chose, there is only an empty folder with the name "gdk-stopwatch-sample". So, what's going wrong?

I have also tried downloading the zip file from github and then trying to open it via another selection in the Android Studio Startup window like *Open an Existing Android Studio Project* or *Import Non-Android Studio Project* but I am very new to Android development and I cannot seem to choose the correct gradle import settings so the projects never run or build correctly if I can manage to open them. I am convinced that the easiest way to start this process will be to check the project out through version control, but I don't understand what's going wrong and I can't find any documentation that discusses this problem. I would greatly appreciate any help on how to get this going.

App found here:
https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-stopwatch-sample

Instructions found here under *Before You Begin*:
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/patterns/ongoing-task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met with the same problem as you. (also Android Studio 1.0.2, but on windows) 
Here's the solution I've found:

1. for Check-out/clone issue, make sure you've installed git and it is accessible in your android_studio.

At Android_studio, set the git in the following settings page 
(My path is under Windows...)
[image]

2. to open the *gdk-stopwatch-sample* project (using the local gradle_2.2.1), 
    make the following modifications

   (1).   *\gdk-stopwatch-sample\app\build.gradle*
   (old) **runProguard** false 
   (new) **minifyEnabled** false

   (2). \gdk-stopwatch-sample\build.gradle 
   (old) classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+' 
   (new) classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**1.0.0+**'

   (3). install *SDK Build tools v20* (from SDK manager), if not yet.

Comment: How do I check if it is accessible in my path?

Comment: Changing runProguard to minifyEnabled allowed me to run the samples, but I still haven't figured out how to successfully check the project out from github.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check the settings of "Path to git" from you android_studio

Answer (score 0):

If your gradle plugin version is 0.14.0 or higher, you have to go to your build.gradle file and change "runProguard" to "minifyEnabled".  You can read more about the recent changes here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system