# Cannot Run the Project Import from Github

Tags: android, android-studio, github, version-control

My purpose is to import Android project from Github.

---

First method

1. Use "Check out project from Version Control" -> "Git"
   Then I enter Git Repository URL， press Clone.
2. I choose "create project from existing source"
3. Here is the result. The Run button is disable.https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD6lg.png

---

Second method

1. Use "Check out project from Version Control" -> "Git"
   Then I enter Git Repository URL， press Clone.
2. I choose "Import project from external model", choose"Gradle".
3. Can only choose "Use local gradle distribution"
4. Here is the result. The Run button still disable.https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5YLO.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [import prerequisite for Android project](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#prerequisites).

I see in that [`survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android`](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/) project:

- some `build.gradle` which still have [mentions of `runProguard`](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=runProguard) instead of `minifyEnabled`.
- some [references to `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version which are not 1.0.0+](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=com.android.tools.build%3Agradle)

Try and fix those first, and then try, as described in "[Check out Project from Version Control Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27981123/6309)".